# как вывести 'некорректный вод' ,если ввод будет, допустим, -1 7 7?

Tags: golang

```go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a int
    var b int
    var c int
    fmt.Scan(&a, &b, &c)
    if a == c && a == b && c == b {
        fmt.Println("Все числа равны")
    } else if a != c && a != b && c != b {
        fmt.Println("Все числа разные")
    } else if a == c || a == b || b == c {
       fmt.Println("Два числа равны")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Некорректный ввод")
    }
}
```

**условия**

**Все числа равны**, если все три числа равны.

**Два числа равны**, если любые два числа из трех равны.

**Все числа разные**, если все три введенных числа различаются.

Если во входных данных есть ошибка, например, введены отрицательные числа, то программа должна выводить сообщение **Некорректный ввод**.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [помогите, не могу понять где ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540499/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: В условии на "два числа равны" нет смысла проверять на неравенство чисел. Это совершенно ничего не дает. Точно так же в третьей части не нужно проверять ``a != c`` И ОДНОВРЕМЕННО ``c != a`` (и т.п.) Это ОДНО И ТО ЖЕ!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы не читаете эти числа вообще:

```go
var a int
var b int
var c int
if a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 {
    fmt.Scan(&a, &b, &c)
}
```

т.е. вы читаете числа из консоли только тогда когда у вас a, b и с больше 0. Но после создания этих переменных они как раз и будут равны 0, т.е. условие не выполнится и вы не будете читать их из консоли. Просто уберите условие:

```go
var a int
var b int
var c int
fmt.Scan(&a, &b, &c)
```